# modifying properties-service.xml

Tags: java, xml, configuration, jboss, properties

I have a question related to the properties-service.xml. There is a value inside this file that needs to be updated every once in a while programmatically. So I have the following questions about this operation which I wasn't able to find some details about them:

- Is there a way to update properties-service.xml programatically other than parsing it and changing the value? If parsing is the only way, is there an available method of retrieving the location of the used properties file?
- Can we reload the properties-service.xml after the update without restarting jboss or do I need to set the property manually?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get location of the properties file - acquire System property "**jboss.server.home.dir**" and suffix "**/deploy/properties-service.xml**" to it.
2. Once you save your changes to properties files, JBoss will hot-deploy it as it scans for changes every 5 seconds.  If it doesn't hot deploy check value of attribute "ScanEnabled" in  /conf/jboss-service.xml to confirm that hot deploy is enabled